# My screen turns off and I want to disable this feature

Tags: raspbian

I am a total newbe but I have many years in the computer business so I have some technical knowledge.

I just purchased a Pi4, 4gb beginners kit including official PS, cables and Noob card and everything seems to work. The Temp during idle is 50c and when running chrome, its steady at 56c, and I am using a standard PC HDM1 monitor

But when I am inactive, the monitor turns off after maybe 20 minutes and I need to move the mouse to turn it on -

Can anybody tell me how to set it so it always stays on?

Thaks

Bill

Comment: So you have two problems: (1) Rpi too hot (50+C, (2) HDMI monitor "turning off" too soon, wish to make it longer than 20 minutes. For (1) I know it is OK to let Rpi running at 60c to 80C, and Rpi has some sort "thermal protect" mechanism which decreases master clock frequency when too hot. I am a Windows guy and I can easily set the "turn off" time in the Windows appearance setting.  I am not aware of similar thing Rpi GUI Desktop.  Perhaps I can check it out and let you know. Of course You could set the turn off time in certain config.txt file, but I find terminal commands scary! :)

Comment: Are you using the Pi in console mode or GUI mode?

Comment: I am running in GUI mode - Like windows...